# Yandex Map Api работа с существующими на карте метками

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api

3 день изучаю работу с апи, но так нигде и не нашёл следующих возможностей:

1) Обрабатывать нажатие на не пользовательские объекты на карте (рестораны, кафе, аптеки и.т.д), затем получая координаты этих меток.

2) Отображение объектов карты определённых категорий. Например только аптеки или только рестораны.

3) Могу ли для существующего объекта переопределить balloon?

4) Как запретить открывание ballon при клике на любой из объектов карты.

Вопросы относятся только к уже существующим объектам на карте, которые стандартно отображаются. О том как работать со своими кастомными объектами понятно, документация только об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Изменять данные карты средствами API нельзя, более того это запрещено Пользовательским соглашением (п. 2.3.10.2) https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/